# Levi–Civita connection and geodesics on $P(n)$ with the trace metric

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, geodesic

I'm trying to verify the formula for the Levi–Civita connection on $P(n)$ (the manifold of positive-definite symmetric matrices) with the trace metric defined by $g_X(A, B) = \operatorname{tr}(X^{-1}AX^{-1}B)$ for $A, B\in T_XP(n)\cong S(n)$ (the vector space of symmetric matrices) against the known formula for the geodesics. The formula for the connection is given [here](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/220146481_The_Riemannian_Geometry_of_the_Space_of_Positive-Definite_Matrices_and_Its_Application_to_the_Regularization_of_Positive-Definite_Matrix-Valued_Data) as $$\nabla_AB = -\frac{1}{2}(AX^{-1}B+BX^{-1}A)$$ and the geodesics $\gamma : \mathbb{R}^+\to P(n)$ are given for $\gamma(0) = X$ and $\gamma'(0) = A$ as $$\gamma(t) = X^{1/2}\exp(tX^{-1/2}AX^{-1/2})X^{1/2}$$ By the definition of the geodesics on a Riemannian manifold, the curve $\gamma$ must have zero acceleration at all points, or $\nabla_{\dot{\gamma}}\dot{\gamma}\equiv 0$. We have \begin{align*} \dot{\gamma}(t) &= X^{1/2}(X^{-1/2}AX^{-1/2})\exp(tX^{-1/2}AX^{-1/2})X^{1/2} \\ &= AX^{-1/2}\exp(tX^{-1/2}AX^{-1/2})X^{1/2} \\ &= X^{1/2}\exp(tX^{-1/2}AX^{-1/2})X^{-1/2}A \end{align*} Then, \begin{align*} \gamma(t)^{-1}\dot{\gamma}(t) &= X^{-1/2}\exp(-tX^{-1/2}AX^{-1/2})X^{-1/2}X^{1/2}\exp(tX^{-1/2}AX^{-1/2})X^{-1/2}A \\ &= X^{-1}A \end{align*} Note that this also allows us to conclude that the geodesic is correctly parametrized by length, as $$g_{\gamma(t)}(\dot{\gamma}(t), \dot{\gamma}(t)) = \operatorname{tr}(X^{-1}AX^{-1}A) = g_X(A, A)$$ I don't quite see how this will give us the required zero acceleration $\nabla_{\dot{\gamma}}\dot{\gamma}\equiv 0$. Am I misinterpreting something here? Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure this geodesics is parametrized by length?

Comment: We have $$g_{\gamma(t)}(\dot{\gamma}(t), \dot{\gamma}(t)) = g_X(A, A)$$ so yes, $\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t}g_{\gamma(t)}(\dot{\gamma}(t), \dot{\gamma}(t)) = 0$. To see this, note that $\dot{\gamma}(t)\gamma(t)^{-1} = AX^{-1}$ as shown above and that the trace is invariant under cyclic permutation.

Comment: I don't think you can eliminate the exponential term.

Comment: Why not? Consider a matrix $U$. Note that $U$ and $-U$ commute, so $e^Ue^{-U} = e^{U-U} = I$.

Comment: Ok I am wrong..

Comment: It's no problem! I added a line in the question showing that the geodesic is correctly parametrized, since it is a good thing to check.

Comment: I think the problem comes from the connection. Your expression of connection is independent of the variation of $B$ and doesn't satisfy the Leibniz rule.

Comment: You should check whether the expression in this article is under certain assumption. Otherwise there is no geodesics in this manifold.

Comment: The expression for the connection? I'm quite sure that the formula for the geodesics is correct. The formula for the connection is also given in [this](https://repozitorium.omikk.bme.hu/bitstream/handle/10890/293/ertekezes.pdf) Ph.D. thesis of Andai Attila as Equation 2.232 and is derived in full.

Comment: I might be misinterpreting how to make use of the Levi–Civita connection, but I'm not really sure how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In expression you have written for $\nabla_AB$ the right side is incorrect; As XT Chen points out, it does not depend at all on the the derivative of $B$ and doesn't satisfy the Leibniz rule. The right side is in fact equal to the Christoffel symbol $\Gamma$ of the connection,
$$
\Gamma(A,B)|_X=-\frac{1}{2}(AX^{-1}B+BX^{-1}A)
$$
The Christoffel symbol is related to the covariant derivative by
$$
\nabla_AB=\partial_AB+\Gamma(A,B)
$$
Where $\partial$ is the derivative induced by the coordinates. In this case, it can be computed as
$$
(\partial_AB)|_X=\frac{d}{dt}(B|_{X+tA})|_{t=0}
$$
Notice that in the spacial case that that the coordinate representation of $B$ is constant, we have $\nabla_AB=\Gamma(A,B)$. In general, however, the derivative term needs to be included. The line from the linked paper is seems to discussing just such a vector field with constant coefficients, defined by $Y=Y^\alpha E_\alpha$, with $Y^\alpha$ constant.

As an aside, I humbly take issue with some of the linked paper's treatment of covariant derivatives. The notion of "restricting" $\nabla$ to a bilinear map $T_pM\times T_pM\to T_pM$ doesn't make sense, generally speaking. If these topics are unfamiliar to you, I would recommend looking at a more standard reference first.

Comment: This clears a lot up, thank you! For the purpose of a Riemannian manifold, where there isn't necessarily a notion of addition, does it make sense instead to write $$(\partial_AB)_X = \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t}(B|_{\gamma(t)})|_{t=0}$$ for $\gamma(t)$ the curve with $\gamma(0) = X$ and $\gamma'(0) = A$?

Comment: That expression won't make sense in general, since taking the derivative involves subtracting $B|_{\gamma(t)}$ and $B|_{\gamma(0)}$, and these belong to different tangent spaces. $\partial$ is a coordinate dependent operator; in a particular set of coordinates it is just the componentwise directional derivative, i.e. $$\partial_U V=\partial_{U^i\partial_i}(V^j\partial_j)=U^i\left(\frac{\partial V^j}{\partial x^i}\right)\partial_j$$ where $\partial_i$ is the standard basis of $TM$ induced by the coordinates.

Comment: You're right, I was lazy about the tangent spaces. If we define a parallel transport map $P^{\gamma}_{t_1,t_2} : T_{\gamma(t_1)}M\to T_{\gamma(t_2)}M$ along the curve $\gamma$, is it equivalent to taking $\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t}(B|_{\gamma(t)})|_{t=0}$ as $\lim_{t\to 0} \frac{P^{\gamma}_{t,0} B|_{\gamma(t)}-B|_{\gamma(0)}}{t}$?

Comment: Only if $P$ is the parallel transport induced by $\partial$. Even then, it's a bit circular. Since $\partial$ is coordinate dependent, it makes more sense to define it in terms of the local coordinates that induce it.